# Javascript in Selenium automation project(Java) or how to scroll not <select> list

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I've got such trouble.
During automation on site I need to automate dropdown with flags. But it done not by "select" but by "div" and "li" in it.
I can take list of elements but there are 237 elements and to click on one of them I need to scroll down. To do it I try to use JavaScript.

```
public void selectFlagByNumber(int number) {
    String script = "var countryList = document.getElementsByClassName(\"country-list\")[0];"
            + "var index = arguments[0];"
            + "if (index >= 0 && index <= countryList.childNodes.length) {"
            // open dropdown
            + "document.getElementsByClassName(\"selected-flag\")[0].click();"
            // select item
            + "countryList.childNodes[index].click()";

    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)getParent().getDriver();
    js.executeScript(script, 6);
    System.out.println("Script executed");
}
```

And script itself working if put in on browser.
But I got en error when run it with Selenium code:

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
>     (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.140)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522940 (1a76f96f66e3ca7b8e57d503b4dd3bccfba87af1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T18:33:54.468Z'
>   System info: host: 'VIW20083', ip: '172.16.150.64', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_11'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

Could someone suggest what could be wrong or how is it possible to do it another way?

Thank you.

Comment: You didn't close `if` statement. `}` is missing

Comment: :) Thanks.It was embarrassing :)

Comment: Did it solve your issue?

Comment: Accept my answer please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't close `if` statement. `}` is missing